# File does not reside within any path specified using proto_path

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am testing out importing .proto file from another directory.

**$GOPATH/src/A/A.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3"; 
package A;
 message SomeMsg {
     string  msg = 2;
     int64   id  = 3;
 }
```

**$GOPATH/src/B/B.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3"; 
package B; import "A/A.proto";
 message Msg {
     SomeMsg s = 1;
 }
```

I'm doing this:
in folder A:

```
protoc A.proto --go_out=.
```

and then in folder B:

```
protoc B.proto --go_out=. --proto_path=$GOPATH/
```

But I will get this error:

> B.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Error seems clear enough to me, it is saying that you need to specify the exact directory that B.proto is in

```
protoc B.proto --go_out=. --proto_path=$GOPATH/src/B
```

or if you are in folder B already,

```
protoc B.proto --go_out=.
```

Comment: "it's harder than you think" ---- Of course they are funny! I burst into laughter when I read it the first time myself.

Comment: It's confusing because the phrasing is very odd, uses the passive voice and the word "encompasses" actually means *any* directory above the file itself. Shorter and clearer would simply be "B.proto not found. Provide the path to .proto files using --proto_path"

Comment: but why can't the tool find the proto from current directory?

Comment: @LeiYang Well, it actually does that if no `--proto_path` is specified. Once you specify one going somewhere other than the current directory, then you have to specify the current directory as well in another `-proto_path`. I got this error, and I kept thinking it couldn't find the import directory, but it was actually the .proto in the current directory that it couldn't find because I didn't do this.

Answer (score 3):

`protoc B.proto --go_out=. --proto_path=$GOPATH/src/B --progo_path=.` worked for me.

`--progo_path=.` may help you too.

Comment: Adding the --proto_path=. did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

**Case1:** The `'..'` cannot used in path of .proto file if all paths are in 'absolute format'.

**Case2:** Another word to explain that error. The relevant path and absolute path cannot use in mixed within -I and path to .proto file, since the 'prefix' means the STRING-PREFIX instead of 'a path can jump to by relevant-path in filesystem'.

=========
It seems that the `.proto` and `-I` its resided in should use both relative path or both, otherwise error occured.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a reference to a proto file in a C# project, note that the path to the proto file is case sensitive. In my case a link to the proto file in a .net 4.6 project (VS2022 on Windows), looks like this. When I use uppercase characters in the path, the compiler gives the "*File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path*" error, as mentioned. However, I **can** use relative paths.

```
<!-- all path characters  must be lower case -->
<Protobuf Include="..\path.to.proto\protos\myfile.proto">
  <Link>Protos\myfile.proto</Link>
</Protobuf>
```

Also note that you must change the csproj file manually to be sure that the xml-element is called 'Protobuf' and not 'None'! Of course, only applicable for visual studio project situations.